# Joomla article variable height without scrollbar

Tags: html, css, joomla

I have created a jquery plugin which is rendered within a Joomla article, via some HTML.

Now, there is an action where it adds some content in at the bottom of the initial (the red content): http://take.ms/eMqIz

Now, I have added an overflow:auto in the article in order to show all the content, but it is shown with the help of a scrollbar ON the ARTICLE, as shown here: http://take.ms/sOOL1

How can I remove the vertical article's scrollbar and "push" the footer content, in order to use the main vertical scrollbar to navigate?

Thanks!

Comment: Rather than using `overflow: auto;` which clips the content and adds a scroll bar, try using `overflow: visible;`

Comment: I've tried it, in `overflow:auto;` it adds the scrollbar, in the `overflow:visible;` does nothing....

Comment: Can you please provide a link to you site?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately it's still in localhost...

Answer (score 0):

you can use statement like that in your css file

> min-height: 500px;

and make sure that

> height:

is not used in your css file for that div

In google inspect element do verify that calculated value does not contain

> height:

Comment: Hello arslan! If I use min-height, I can define the exact height of the window, although it is not dynamic... it stays open for example. In every parent, it does not calculate any height...